# the 'select' call keep find client socket could be read

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, tcp

It's hard for me to describe my question, though, the title above maybe somehow not clear.

I have a ordinary tcp server which have a listen socket, and can accept up to 32 clients, I have created sockets for each client, and I use select system call to monitor which client could be read, following code is a snippet of my program.

where, `rset` is a member variable of my class and its type is `fd_set`. I have zeroed it using `FD_ZERO` in the constructor.

`timeo` is also a member variable, type is `struct timeval` initialized with 10 seconds.

`this->sock` is again a member variable, used for listening and accepting new clients. I have called `FD_SET(this->sock, &rset)` before.

`print_trace` is just a macro which print the message and append a '\n'.

```
 while(1) {
     int count = select(FD_SETSIZE, &rset, /*&wset*/ NULL, NULL, &timeo);
     printf("%d fds\n", count);

     if(count) {     
        if(FD_ISSET(this->sock, &rset)) {
            // new connection comes and now this line will not blocked 
            if((csocks[sock_count] = accept(this->sock, NULL, NULL))) {
                FD_SET(csocks[sock_count], &rset);

                ++sock_count;
            }           
         } else {  
             print_trace("there are clients can be read.");      
             for(int i = 0 ; i < sock_count ; ++i) {
                if(FD_ISSET(csocks[i], &rset)) {
                    char buffer[512] = {0};
                    recv(csocks[i], buffer, 512, 0);
                    printf("here client socket number: %d, i=%d, message: %s\n", csocks[i], i, buffer);
                }
             }
         }
     }

     timeo.tv_sec = 10;
     timeo.tv_usec = 0;
 }
```

I know I am not re-enable the `this->sock` using `FD_SET`, for select will clear all the bits when timeout, but it have no concern with my trouble.

my trouble is, when I run the server program, and in 10 seconds, I run a client program to connect to this server, the `select` returns 1 normally, so that the client socket be created and be added to `rset`, and then, the server goes to next loop, caution! now, right now, terminate the client program immediately, don't wait for the `select` returns.

Okay, now the trouble will reappear, the server program keep printing the following info:

```
1 fds
there are clients can be read.
here client socket number: 6, i=2, message: 
1 fds
there are clients can be read. 
here client socket number: 6, i=2, message:  
1 fds
there are clients can be read.
here client socket number: 6, i=2, message: 
1 fds
there are clients can be read.
here client socket number: 6, i=2, message: 
...
...
```

I have use `tcpdump` monitor the connection, when terminate the client, it just send an FIN packet, and the server program just send an ACK packet, there is no any other data flowing the connection.

why the `select` keep finding the client socket can be read while it just read empty message(as the printing message showing)?

Any help will be appreciated.

update: I know the usage of `select` method clearly, I thought I don't use this method properly so I have had spent about one hour to study this method, in order to solve my problem, but found no result still.

Comment: FYI, don't use `FD_SETSIZE` in your `select`.  It is a little bit more work to keep track of your file descriptors but it saves having to look through the whole set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're ignoring the result returned by recv(), which is itself an error, and specifically you're ignoring the possibility that it's zero, which is end of stream, on which you should close the socket, so you don't just select on EOS again.

Comment: thanks! it is the answer! It seems that I make things complicated.